# How to delete files older than 7 days but keep last 6 files of 1st of every month in Amazon S3?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, amazon-s3, scripting

We have a backup strategy where every day db dumps are taken and uploaded to s3 bucket. We want to delete backups from s3 which are older than 7 days, but we also want to keep backup of 1st of every month for last 6 months. The backup files are in the format db_dump20220430220001.gz

Comment: Run a `find` with `-mtime`.  This will give you a list of all files older than 7 days.  Then in the `-exec`, add an `if` statement to delete the file if its filename is not `db_dump20????01*`.  Hence all files for year `20??`, month `??`, day 01.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic capability to perform this logic.

However, you could use Tags to accomplish the goal:

- Configure the Amazon S3 bucket to **trigger an AWS Lambda function** whenever new objects are created in the bucket/path
- Code the Lambda function to **add a tag to the object unless it is the first backup of the month** (it could do this based purely on the date, or it could look for existing backups in the bucket/path)
- Configure an Amazon S3 Lifecycle rule to **delete objects that are older than 7 days *AND* have the above tag** (which means the first backup of each month would *not* be deleted)
- Add another Lifecycle rule to **delete objects older than 6 months** (which *would* delete that backup)